# Pivot query about sales data

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm trying to do a pivot query but don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I have three columns, AgentId, AgentName, product type and count of each product for each agent i-e group by agent name, id and product type.

I want to rotate the columns so that I can get an agent id column, agent name column, and values of product type (Accidental, Juvenile, Guaranteed Issue and Simplified Issue) as columns and their count as the values of these 4 columns. Below is my query.

```
select agent_id, agent_name, quote_product_type__c 
,count(*) as num
 from dbt.opportunities
 where quote_product_type__c in ('Accidental','Juvenile','Guaranteed Issue', 'Simplified Issue')
 group by agent_id, agent_name, quote_product_type__c 
order by agent_name
```

Please can anyone tell me how can I write a pivot query for it. I'll be very obliged.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Different products have different pivot functionality. (if any.))

Comment: Periscope, Amazon redshift

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select agent_id, agent_name,
       sum( (quote_product_type__c = 'Accidental')::int ) as Accidental,
       sum( (quote_product_type__c = 'Juvenile')::int ) as Juvenile,
       sum( (quote_product_type__c = 'Guaranteed Issue')::int ) as Guaranteed_Issue,
       sum( (quote_product_type__c = 'Simplified Issue')::int ) as Simplified_Issue
from dbt.opportunities
where quote_product_type__c in (,'','', 'Simplified Issue')
group by agent_id, agent_name 
order by agent_name
```